# Animate Edit text color change from outside to inside

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

I have custom edit text that allows to change and animate background color, but when I try to switch the animation to go from outside to inside, the edit text takes the paint color and overlay over edit text highlight color. So my activated color for edit text is blue and I am trying to change to green with animation, the outside in animation in the class below ends up with a mix of blue and green.

But the inside out animation work fine, I am not sure why. Any help would be appreciated.

So basically playInsideOut() method does animation fine but playOutsideInAnimation() ends up with weird color.

```
public class AnimatedEditText extends EditText {
    private Paint paint;
    private Rect rect;
    private static final int ANIMATION_DURATION = 500;

    public AnimatedEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public AnimatedEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public AnimatedEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public AnimatedEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        resetPaint(getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));
    }

    public void playAnimationInsideOut(int color) {
        getBackground().setColorFilter(null);
        resetPaint(getResources().getColor(color));

        rect.top = getMeasuredHeight() - getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.line_offset);
        rect.bottom = getMeasuredHeight();
        rect.left = getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
        rect.right = getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
        ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(PropertyValuesHolder.ofInt("left", rect.left, 0), PropertyValuesHolder.ofInt("right", rect.right, getMeasuredWidth()));
        animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                rect.left = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue("left");
                rect.right = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue("right");
            }
        });
        animator.setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION);
        animator.start();
    }

    public void playAnimationOutsideIn() {
        getBackground().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.green), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

        rect.top = getMeasuredHeight() -     getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.line_offset);
        rect.bottom = getMeasuredHeight();
        rect.left = getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
        rect.right = getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
        ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(PropertyValuesHolder.ofInt("left", 0, rect.left), PropertyValuesHolder.ofInt("right",getMeasuredWidth(), rect.right ));

        animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                rect.left = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue("left");
                rect.right = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue("right");

            }

        });

        animator.setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION);
        animator.start();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);

        invalidate();
    }

    private void resetPaint(int color) {
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP));
        paint.setColor(color);

        rect = new Rect();
        setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the value of `R.color.green`?

Comment: Here are colors

        <color name="green">#66CD00</color>
        <color name="grey">#666666</color>
         <color name="blue">#00abc7</color>

Comment: This isn't surprising to me, there are a new things I would try, call `super.onDraw()` after you draw your rect. Also, never called ``invalidate()` in `onDraw` this will result in an infinite loop. Call this in your animation update listener.